# searching for records from database using Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sqlite

i'm trying to make a boolean function that returns whether a string from Arraylist was found in the database, it keeps crashing my app and i'm not sure why.

```
  ArrayList<String> suggestedWords = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
     //   mApp.setGlobalArray(suggestedWords);

        for (int i = 0; i < suggestedWords.size(); i++) {
            if(hasObject(suggestedWords.get(i))){
                Log.d("GOT IT RIGHT",suggestedWords.get(i));
            }
        }
```

this is the boolean function

```
 public boolean hasObject(String id) {
    db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqdb = db.getWritableDatabase();

    String selectString = "SELECT * FROM wordsdata WHERE Enwd"+ " =?";


    Cursor cursor = sqdb.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{id});

    boolean hasObject = false;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        hasObject = true;


        int count = 0;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            count++;
        }
        //here, count is records found
        Log.d("IS WORD THERE", String.format("%d records found", count));



    }

    cursor.close();        
    db.close();              
    return hasObject;
}
```

EDIT : the logcat

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Square (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from wordsdata where Enwd = Square
```

and the database i'm using is a pre-existing database from my Assets file and i've already tested it my database has no issues

EDIT2 : my DataBaseHelper

```
class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
//database variables
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "voicedata.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "wordsdata";
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String Enwd = "Enwd";
private static final String Enno = "Enno";
private static final String Enyes = "Enyes";

private final Context mContext;


DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mContext = context;
}
```

here is my full logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.nourhamran.anothertest, PID: 1142
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=999, result=-1, data=Intent {  launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has extras) }} to activity {com.example.nourhamran.anothertest/com.example.nourhamran.anothertest.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: plane (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from wordsdata where Enwd = plane
                                                                              #################################################################
                                                                              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                (no such column: plane (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from wordsdata where Enwd = plane)
                                                                              #################################################################
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4472)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: plane (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from wordsdata where Enwd = plane
                                                                              #################################################################
                                                                              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                (no such column: plane (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from wordsdata where Enwd = plane)
                                                                              #################################################################
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1005)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:570)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1697)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1636)
                                                                                  at com.example.nourhamran.anothertest.MainActivity.iswordindb(MainActivity.java:284)
                                                                                  at com.example.nourhamran.anothertest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:229)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7256)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4468)
```

Comment: The logcat should tell you exactly why the app crashed. Please add it

Comment: it's giving me "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Square (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from wordsdata where Enwd = Square" and honestly i've tried so many things i'm getting very confused @cricket_007

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that error and the CREATE TABLE statement for `wordsdata`

Comment: @cricket_007 just did!

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` statement, please?

Comment: @cricket_007 i'm not sure if that's what you meant..

Comment: There are the words "create table" in your `DataBaseHelper` class. Please show it all

Comment: @cricket_007 i'm extending my DataBaseHelper to SQLiteAssetsHelper, so no,  dont have create table in my databasehelper

Comment: Ah, I thought you had `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query isn't valid because `Square` isn't quoted like so

```
Select * from wordsdata where Enwd = 'Square'
```

---

But, you are using `rawQuery` correctly, so I see no reason why the code shown would cause that error, so I think you're getting that error elsewhere, where you do `"Enwd = " + id`

As an alternative to what you have, implement this method within `DataBaseHelper`.

```
 public boolean hasObject(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = getReadableDatabase();

    String selectString = "SELECT * FROM wordsdata WHERE " + Enwd + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = sqdb.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{id});
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    long count = cursor.getCount();

    boolean hasObject = count > 0;

    //here, count is records found
    Log.d("IS WORD THERE", String.format("%d records found", count));

    cursor.close();        
    db.close();              
    return hasObject;
}
```

Use it outside

```
db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
boolean hasId = db.hasObject(id);
```

---

Note: You should really be doing `COUNT(*)` in the query anyway to make SQLite do the count itself

Comment: Try using `Enwd + "='?'";` (Note the single quotes)

Comment: If that doesn't work, edit the question again with the full logcat, not just the exception

Comment: just posted the full logcat @cricket_007

Comment: The error exists at the method... `MainActivity.iswordindb`, and not `DataBaseHelper.hasObject`, so I don't think you followed my answer

Comment: oh yes! there was nother search function i tried before and i thought i deleted it, it works now.. thank you! @cricket_007